# Paginate SQL SELECT query to improve performance

Tags: sql, performance

I have a table that has 22,408,554 records. It is taking 8 seconds to get the results from the following query (via ajax).

```
SELECT TOP 20 [COLUMN_1]
FROM [sample_db1].[dbo].[sample_table]
WHERE id = 10
```

I paginated using the following query, but this did not help the performance.

```
SELECT * 
FROM    
    (SELECT    
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum, *
     FROM      
         [sample_db1].[dbo].[sample_table]
     WHERE     
          id = 10) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   
    RowNum >= 1 AND RowNum < 20
ORDER BY 
    RowNum
```

I am looking for suggestions that will reduce the query time.

Comment: Need more info-- Which DB vendor&Version? What are Index stats on ID column?  How many have ID#=10?

Comment: Pagination does NOT make sense in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause. Please add an explicit ordering of the rows.

Comment: so what is the better solution for it. I wrapped it inside store procedure but this could not heled me

Comment: (I think you are using SQL Server, if that is true add that as a tag to your question) For SQL Server: get the actual execution plan, paste into https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ - any query performance tuning starts with the execution plan